# Spring boot push notification

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, notifications, server-sent-events

I have a web application using spring boot as a back end and vue.js as a front end, and I have a script python capture, this last can add row to database so I nee d to push notification to users, How can I do it ?

```
@PostMapping("/plate")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createPositionOc(@RequestParam String plate) {

    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    List<Car> cars = carController.getAllCars();
    boolean exist = cars.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getPlate().equals(plate));

    List<Car> carsIn = carController.getAllCarsIn();
    boolean existIn = carsIn.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getPlate().equals(plate));


    List<Position> free = getAllPositiosFree();

    PositionOcp position = new PositionOcp(free.get(0).getId_pos(), plate, 
 myDateObj.format(myFormatObj));

    if (exist && free.size() > 0 && !existIn) {
        PositionOcp createdPositionOc = positionOcpRepository.save(position);
        //send notification
    }    

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will achieve this, first by reading spring documentation about push notifications or tutorials like this one : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket